# Save pandas dataframe to the existing Excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

When I'm trying to save pandas dataframe to the existing Excel sheet it works.

```py
workbook = load_workbook('excel_file.xlsx')

def prepare_to_validate_sheet(): 
    to_validate_sheet = workbook['To Validate']
    dataframe = pd.read_csv('to_validate.csv', sep = ';')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl', mode = "a", if_sheet_exists = "replace")
    writer.worksheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'To Validate', index = False)
    writer.close()
```

But when I'm trying to use next function to change another sheet `Installation`, the previous one `To Validate` becomes empty. Meanwhile the changes are saved on the `Installation` sheet.

```py
def prepare_installation_sheet():
    installation_sheet = workbook['Installation']
    installation_sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = installation_title
    installation_sheet.cell(row = 4, column = 1).value = installation_text
    workbook.save('excel_file.xlsx')
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: can you provide a fully reproducible example? what is the content of `to_validate.csv` and the undefined variables?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do but mixing openpyxl and pandas calls like this is likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "ExcelWriter" class from the pandas library to write to specific sheets in the workbook without overwriting the entire workbook.

```
def prepare_to_validate_sheet(): 
    to_validate_sheet = workbook['To Validate']
    dataframe = pd.read_csv('to_validate.csv', sep = ';')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl', mode = "a", if_sheet_exists = "replace")
    writer.book = workbook
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'To Validate', index = False)
    writer.save()

def prepare_installation_sheet():
    installation_sheet = workbook['Installation']
    installation_sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = installation_title
    installation_sheet.cell(row = 4, column = 1).value = installation_text
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl', mode = "a", if_sheet_exists = "replace")
    writer.book = workbook
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)
    installation_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Installation', index = False)
    writer.save()
```

You can now write to particular sheets in the workbook without overwriting the entire workbook through these changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('excel_file.xlsx')

to_validate_sheet = workbook['To Validate']
dataframe = pd.read_csv('to_validate.csv', sep=';')
with pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    writer.book = workbook
    writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='To Validate', index=False)

installation_sheet = workbook['Installation']
installation_sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = installation_title
installation_sheet.cell(row=4, column=1).value = installation_text

# Save changes to the original file
workbook.save('excel_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. But question more about how to save `To Validate` changes to the original file. Because I will use it in the all my functions from the next steps

Comment: All manipulations with `workbook` and `workbook.save()` work as expected. The problem seems to be only with `writer.close()`.

Comment: @macder I have updated the answer yes the issue was with writer.close() you need to use that as you have perform all the work on the file

Comment: Unfortunately I have to separate changes for each sheet to new python method and I can't combine it together

Comment: that will work just make workbook = load_workbook('excel_file.xlsx') as global for this python file and close it as you are done will all the work

Comment: Actually - no, I moved `workbook.save('excel_file.xlsx')` to the `main()` but it still doesn't save changes for `To Validate`